# что значит эта переменная? OBJECTS=$(SOURCES: .c=.o) . Что за .с=.о?

Tags: makefile

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -c –Wall
EXECUTABLE = prog
SOURCES = main.c foo.c

OBJECTS=$(SOURCES: .c=.o)

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)
$(EXECUTABLE) : $(OBJECTS)
        $(CC) $(OBJECTS) –o $@
.c.o:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
clean:
        rm–rf*.o *.exe
```

про знак < нашел инфу, но что за равно в переменной objects?
Мое подозрение, что это задает сразу 2 зависимости одной строчкой(с .с и с .о)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это замена суффиксов.  Из
[стандарта](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html):

> *Macro expansions using the forms
> `$(string1[:subst1=[subst2]])` or
> `${string1[:subst1=[subst2]]}` can be used to replace all
> occurrences of `subst1` with `subst2` when the
> macro substitution is performed.  The `subst1` to be replaced
> shall be recognized when it is a suffix at the end of a word in
> `string1` (where a *word*, in this context, is defined
> to be a string delimited by the beginning of the line, a <blank>,
> or a <newline>).  (…)*